# AWS ALB 502 Bad gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I am created an infra using API Gateway --> Route 53 --> ALB --> ECS Farate --> Aurora Postgress RDS.

The Application created in Java is working fine using Postname, though when i hit the service from API Gateway -> resources --> Test API, i'm getting "502 Bad gateway" at ALB i suppose.

Current Analysis;

1. Security groups at ALB , ECS and RDS has all Traffic allowed, and also pointing in respecting services IP address.
2. ALB has listener on https: 443 port and target at ECS container http:80, Assigned to Public Subnet
3. by directly hitting ALB DNS : Error 502 BAD Gateway is coming.
4. The ECS task definition has Public IP enabled but getting error: Gateway Timeout, ECS is assigned to Private subnet.
5. I've also tried calling Lambda function from ALB which works fine.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

I am trying to atleast hit one basic API from ALB to ECS

Comment: "i'm getting "502 Bad gateway" at ALB i suppose." That's a big assumption. API Gateway can definitely return 502 errors. You would need to enable API Gateway logs and then view those logs to verify where the error is coming from. You could also view VPC flow logs to see if the request is getting to the load balancer. However the fact you can hit the ALB DNS directly and get the same error is certainly something you should resolve. You say the app is working fine using Postman, but then you list every way to access it and say you get errors all those ways?

Comment: If hitting ALB DNS is giving you 502 Bad Gateway, it is possible that the ALB is either getting a Reset or FIN from its targets which is ECS. Rest of reasons can be found at link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues

I would recommend to first attempt to connect to the private IP of ECS from an EC2 instance in the same VPC. This is to make sure that the target ECS is actually listening as it is expected to

Comment: Also, check that the load balancer's target group says the targets are healthy. If not, that will definitely cause this.

Comment: Also, you said that you have a listener on 443 (HTTPS). Directly hitting ALB DNS would use HTTP (port 80). There are a lot of moving pieces so you should start with enabling logging and looking at one thing at a time